# Python df2gspread.upload() silently failing

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, gspread

I have this code that runs smoothly in PyCharm but doesn't seem to export anything to Google Sheets.

```py
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials_file_here.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet_key = 'spread_sheet_key_entered_here'
wks_name = 'Sheet1'
d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_key, wks_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
```

Comment: I think that your script works. When I saw your script, the service account is used. In this case, about `but doesn't seem to export anything to Google Sheets.`, is the Spreadsheet the same as the Spreadsheet edited by the service account? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Yes, at least I think so. How can I check? I downloaded the credentials from the Google Cloud Console with the account I was using to edit the spreadsheet. The sheet key is the same, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it was found that the Spreadsheet ID of the Spreadsheet edited by the service account is the same as the Spreadsheet you want to see with your browser. In this case, I thought that your script works and you can see the edited Spreadsheet by the service account. I apologize for this.